# Lambda x=> over a List<X> : how to get the position of x in the list

Tags: c#, list, lambda

Let's say I have this line for a type `X` and a `List<X> lx` :

```
Dict<string, X> d = lx.ToDictionary(x => F(Z.g(x).ToString()), x => x)
```

where `Z` is a type with static member function `Y g( X x)` where `Y`is a type implementing `ToString`.

Now I change `Y g( X x)` into `Y g( X x, T t)` where `T` is some type . Let's say I have a `List<T> lt` with same `Count` as `lx`. I would like to change my previous line into (warning, pseudo code) a line :

```
Dict<string, X> d = lx.ToDictionary(x => F(Z.g(x, something).ToString()), x => x)
```

where in the expression `something` I get the index `i` of the `x` inside `lx`, index to which I associate `lt[i]`.

Comment: Please make an actual [mcve], your abbreviated method names and variables make your code very difficult to parse. And why abbreviate `Dict`?!

Comment: @CodeCaster if it's duplicate, I would be glad to see the initial same question, as I didn't succeed in finding it after looking for it ... Thx in advance

Comment: In the yellow box at the top of your question.

Comment: For the purposes of your problem, `F(Z.g(x).ToString())` is the same as `f(x)`. These unnecessary abbreviated function names really distract from the actual functionality, which is `var d = list.ToDictionary(x => f(x), x => x)`. So your actual simple question would be "how to get `list.ToDictionary(x => f(x, index_of_x), x => x)`", and that is answered in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9847547/69809).

Comment: @CodeCaster As of now, no link to any question appears on my side in the yellow box.

Comment: "top of your question"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cztSP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select` to get the index of the item within the collection:

```
lx.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
  .ToDictionary(...);
```

Here I construct an anonymous type to hold both the item and the index, which you can use in the following lambdas.

Comment: It will give me the correct index even if `lt[i]` appears at several positions in `lt` ? (`T = string` in my case.)

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj: this merely iterates through the list and creates a tuple (item, index) for each item. So each item in the list will be processed, yes.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Can you test this code and see if that is what you expected?